# How do I fix "{ expected error" and be able to continue with this challenge?

Tags: interface, comparable, treeset

Noob to java.  Having trouble getting an interface to work.  Getting an error message in my interface "{ expected", but not sure how to remedy since there is one.

main file:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class hw2b 
 {


     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
         TreeSet<Pet> pets = new TreeSet<Pet>();
         pets.add(new Cat("Calico", "5"));
         pets.add(new Cat("Siamese", "10"));
         pets.add(new Dog("Irish Wolfhound", "5"));
         pets.add(new Dog("Border Collie", "10"));

         String choice;

                 choice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your choice\n" +
                                                      "Quit\n" +
                                                      "Print\n" +
                                                      "Add Cat\n" +
                                                      "Add Dog");

                 while (! choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Quit"))
                 {
                     if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Print"))
                     {
                         print(pets); // List will be output in alphabetical order by breed name
                     }

                     else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Add Cat"))
                     {
                         String breed = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter breed of cat");
                         String years = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter age of cat");
                         pets.add(new Cat(breed, years));
                         System.out.println(breed + years + " added");
                     }

                     else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Add Dog"))
                     {
                         String breed = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter breed of dog");
                         String years = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter age of dog");
                         pets.add(new Dog(breed, years));
                         System.out.println(breed + years + " added");
                     }

                     choice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your choice\n" +
                                                          "Quit\n" +
                                                          "Print\n" +
                                                          "Add Cat\n" +
                                                          "Add Dog"); 

                 }

     }

          static private void print(TreeSet data)
          {
              Iterator li = data.iterator();
              System.out.println();
              System.out.println();      
              while (li.hasNext())
              {
                  System.out.println(li.next());
              }
          }

}
```

interface file:

```
public interface Pet implements Comparable  //THE ERROR SAYS THAT THE "{" IS NEEDED ON THIS LINE
{
    public String getBreed();

    public String toString();

    public double getAge();
}
```

A class that implements my interface:

```
public class Cat implements Pet // Dog would be nearly identical to this
{

    private String breed;

    private String years;



    Cat(String breed, String years)
    {
      this.breed = breed;
      this.years = years;
    }



    public String toString()
    {
        return "Pet's breed is " + getBreed() +
               "\nPet's age is " + getAge() +
               "\n";
    }

    public String getBreed()
    {
      return breed;
    }

    public double getAge()
        {
            double age;

              if (years == "1")
              {
                  age = 15;
              }
              else if (years == "2")
              {
                  age = 24;
              }
              else
              {
                  int yrs;
                  yrs = Integer.parseInt(years);
                  age = ((yrs - 2) * 4) + 24;
              }     

            return age;
        }
}
```

My comparator:

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class PetComparator implements Comparator
{
    public int compare(Object a, Object b)
    {
      Pet p1 = (Pet) a;
      Pet p2 = (Pet) b;  
      String p1Breed = p1.getBreed();
      String p2Breed = p2.getBreed(); 
      return p1Breed.compareToIgnoreCase(p2Breed);
    }
}
```

The goal is to be able to start with a TreeSet, add Cat and/or Dog breed and age info to the list, then output the list in sorted order by breed name.  Once I overcome this error I'm sure I can figure out the rest of the challenge, but any insight or pointers would be most welcome.   See comment at the top of the interface code for where the error message says the error is.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces don't implement anything.  Classes do.

The compiler doesn't recognize `implements` as a valid keyword after an `interface` declaration, so (in the absence of the `extends` keyword) it is expecting a semicolon, and didn't get one.

Answer (score 0):

An interface cannot implement another interface. An interface only specifies a contract and so it doesn't make sense to have an interface "implement" something.

Use `extends` instead:

```
public interface Pet extends Comparable {
   ...
}
```

Also, it is not necessary to mark methods in your interface as `public` since all interface methods are implicitly `public`.

Comment: Now I get a message when I compile saying "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Cat.comparTo(Ljava/lang/Object;)I"